If I use the GitLab CI 'trigger' keyword, can I get information about the downstream pipeline to a later job in this pipeline?
In GitLab CI, if I use the trigger keyword to trigger a downstream pipeline, how do I access information about the downstream pipeline, so that I can pass it along to a later job in the upstream pipeline?
For example, let's say I want the later-job job in this pipeline to reference the pipeline id of the downstream pipeline triggered by trigger-job:
stages:
  - early-stage
  - late-stage

trigger-job:
  stage: early-stage
  trigger:
    project: my-group/my-other-project
    strategy: depend

later-job:
  stage: late-stage
  script:
    - echo "The pipeline id of the downstream pipeline triggered by trigger-job is ????????"

Is that possible?

As far as I know, there is no built-in way to achieve this.
Here are a couple of ideas what you could do:

Trigger the initial pipeline back (most native way). At the end of the Pipeline of Project 2, make another trigger to Pipeline 1 that uses variables to only run the missing steps.

Use curl instead of the native trigger keyword. This way you can receive the ID and link to the new pipeline e.g. using jq.

Try to filter out the triggered pipeline. If you can be sure, that your project 1 is the only one that triggers project 2, you could build a pipeline job, that get's you the latest pipeline of a project that was started by a trigger using the Pipelines API:


curl -q --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines?source=trigger" | jq '.[0].id'

